# How can we create an AI to develop mobile apps?

Tags: computer-programming

There are AI creating game, content and more.

I'm thinking on how can AI develop mobile app itself?

The computer languages might easy for AI to learn.

AI can learn a lot from good open source project in github.

The trend prediction can help AI to select the topic for creating a great apps.

There are lots of details to let AI create a great apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't know how to do that yet. The problem is one of scale:

Despite many years of research into program synthesis via heuristic methods, it's still not possible to automatically create programs (e.g. via Genetic Programming (GP), Grammatical Evolution (GE) or Learning Classifier Systems (LCS)) that are thousands of lines long, whether that's for mobile or any other application area.

Contrary to popular belief, alternative formal methods approaches can indeed be used to create sizeable programs, but the kind of interaction that a mobile app would typically require is not easily specified in this way.

The scale at which heuristic approaches are currently viable is closer to the scale of expressions (e.g. single program statements) than entire programs. An intermediate approach is therefore to provide a program template and let GP etc generate the missing parts of the template.

[This paper](http://www.nburles.co.uk/sites/default/files/attachments/templar-a-framework-for-template-method-hyper-heuristics.pdf) describes how to combine Machine Learning with the 'Template Method' Design Pattern in order to create larger programs than would otherwise be possible, giving the specific example of a 'hyper-quicksort'.